# Parsing an expression containing N using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I am parsing an expression using Sympy and getting the following trace:

```
>>> parse_expr("3N", transformations=transformations)`
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Integer' and 'function'
```

From what I could gather, this happens because `N` is seen as a function by the parser and not simply as any other string. The code works fine with a few other symbols that I tested.

Can anyone explain briefly why this is happening? Is there a list of keywords or characters which cannot be parsed using `parse_expr`?

Comment: You should show your definition of `N`.

Comment: N is simply part of a string. I assume that the idea behind parse_expr is to convert characters to symbols. Matt's response below is on the spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the docs ([pitfalls and gotchas](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/gotchas.html)):

> Lastly, it is recommended that you not use I, E, S, N, C, O, or Q for variable or symbol names, as those are used for ... **numeric evaluation (N() is equivalent to evalf() )...** Or better yet, always use lowercase letters for Symbol names. Python will not prevent you from overriding default SymPy names or functions, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It is a bit embarassing that I missed that little bit while going through the documentation. Maybe that bit should also be mentioned in the keywords section along with the symbols section. :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. It certainly wasn't easy to find it.